# How to change channel color on omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I can't find a way to change the color of some channels (edges). using `@display("ls=red,3");` in ned file changes the color of all channels.

Is there a way to change some channels color while executing a simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To change color of a channel in NED use the notation:

   ```
   mod1.out --> { @display("ls=blue,3"); } --> mod2.in;
   ```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, Connection Display Strings](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:connection-displaystrings)

2. To change color of a channel during simulation (i.e. in C++ code of a module) one has to use `getDisplayString()`, for example:

   ```
    cDisplayString& connDispStr = gate("out")->getDisplayString();
    connDispStr.parse("ls=red");
   ```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, Changing Display Strings at Runtime](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:changing-displaystrings-at-runtime)